# what could be the reason behind really slow MongoDB queries?

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack

I am working on a MEAN stack project and since I've connected it with a database, the responses are really slow. I have tried running my project on a friend's computer and it worked just fine, although he's using Linux and I'm on Windows (I'm not sure if that can make any difference). I am closing the connection to the databse after every query, and the number of connections seems okay:

```
> db.serverStatus().connections
{ "current" : 2, "available" : 999998, "totalCreated" : 124, "active" : 1 }
>
```

My Mongo database is really small, just two collections and a couple of documents in each. I can't seem to find any solution online, what could be the problem?
Also, I tried running my friend's project on my computer and had the same problem - slow on mine, fast on his computer. I have never had any problems with my computer, it's relatively new, well maintained and isn't generally slow; so everything's pointing me to my installation of Mongo DB, but I don't know what could I be doing wrong there?

P.S. What I mean when I say really slow - On my computer I have to wait 3-5 seconds for a basic login, while at my friend's computer the response is almost immediate.

Comment: i would suggest running a query from the console, just to check if the problem are the queries or not

Comment: You write: ' I am closing the connection to the databse after every query,'  .   If that means that you are reestablishing connection and auth for each query, that is definitely slow.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti that would then mean it would be slow on my friend's computer too though, wouldn't it? Also, isn't that a good practice, rather than having one connection open the whole time the app is running or having a pool of connections?

Comment: Not necessarily.   Some OSes and file system configs are *much* faster than others.   In general, you should create a single, authenticated (important!) connection to MongoDB.   The drivers handle thread-safe concurrent access so you don't (directly) have to deal with pooling and such.